# When validation fails, redirect back with hash in URL

Tags: laravel

I'm using `FormRequests` for my validation. When validation fails, an exception is thrown, so the body of my controller won't be run.

I have a couple forms on the page and I'm displaying error message at the top. The issue is that it's a bit jarring to have to scroll all the way back down.

I'd like to append a hash in the URL for the HTML to automatically scroll to where the form was submitted.

Is it possible to append a hash to the URL that the validator goes to on error?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: Sorry, I figured since this was very general, I didn't need to share code. See accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override `getRedirectUrl` to add your hash:

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    return $this->redirector->getUrlGenerator()->previous() . '#something';
}
```

Or if you want the default behavior for how it resolves where to redirect to you can just append the fragment:

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    return parent::getRedirectUrl() .'#something';
}
```

Comment: thank you. this was the simplest and easiest to implement. worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

In order to bypass the thrown ValidationException, you have to overwrite the `failedValidation` method of `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`.

```
/**
 * Handle a failed validation attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

In this method instead of throwing an exception, you can set a new custom validator property in your FormRequest class.

```
/*
 * Validator instance updated on failedValidation
 *
 * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
public $validator = null;

/**
 * Overrid Handle a failed validation attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

This will allow you to check if the validator exists and if it fails. So then, in your controller:

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
    // do something
}
```